# How do I selectively load vim plugins?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am using vim-plug and I want to load a certain plugin only for some specific files. How can I do that?

Suppose I have plugin A. How can I load plugin A only for python and cpp?
Similarly, can I prevent vim from loading some plugin B  for html and php files?

Comment: Do you using plugin managers? Are you opening separate Vim instances for every file, or opening Vim once, then editing all the files from it? In latter case, disabling is not possible because plugins are loaded on the beginning of Vim process, thus if a plugin is loaded, it cannot be "unloaded".

Answer (score 1):

```
autocmd FileType cpp,py source  pluginAPath
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [README file](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#example) of vim-plug:

```
" On-demand loading
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on':  'NERDTreeToggle' }
Plug 'tpope/vim-fireplace', { 'for': 'clojure' }
```

This did not help me much, so I looked elsewhere.

Apparently there is a `filetype plugin` option used to define behaviour specific to filetypes. So, to add settings for `.py` files, add `filetype plugin on` in `.vimrc` and create `~/.vim/ftplugin/py.vim` to add settings there.